# What size primes are needed for a good Diffie-Hellman key generation?

Tags: encryption

I've been going through sample code showing how to perform the DH key exchange. Super simple and I understand it. What I don't know, however, is what the appropriate size of p and q should be. In the samples, the numbers are very small. But I'm assuming that, in practice, they should be much larger. How much larger? Would a 16-22 digit prime be sufficient?

Comment: The answer here may help you: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/639/does-the-generator-size-matter-in-diffie-hellman
You might also consider asking your question over there at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So then it looks like a 32 digit prime would fit the bill, if I am understanding things correctly?

Answer (score 5):

Choosing secure groups for DH requires a bit more than just using large enough primes.
Since the primes can be reused it is possible to reuse precomputed parameters.
E.g. [IETF RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526) has a number of proposed groups.
Section 8 estimates the security of each of the proposed groups.

Please, also note that Diffie-Hellman implementations typically avoid small q's (as unfortunately proposed by SquareRootOfTwentyThree). The reason are [subgroup confinement attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_subgroup_confinement_attack). The
IETF groups above have been chosen to avoid such attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by **q** you mean the size of the subgroup modulo **p**, some safe values in 2013 are 224 bits for the former and 2048 bits for the latter. In term of decimal digits that means respectively 68 and 309.

A good website for checking the various opinions about cryptographic key lengths is (no kidding) http://www.keylength.com. In your case, the ones about the discrete logarithm are relevant to you.